# symfony and Travis build composer error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Maybe you can help me, I'm trying to set up Travic-ci account, but on the build I get errors when composer install:

```
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file

  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterCircularReferenceException]                 
  Circular reference detected for parameter "database_driver" ("database_driver" > "database_driver").  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

My travis.yml:

```
language: php

php:

    - 5.5

before_script:

    - cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
    - composer install

script:

    - phpunit -c app
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.*@dev",
        "components/jquery": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "ongr/ongr-strict-standard": "~1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

parameters.yml.dist:

## This file is a "template" of what your parameters.yml file should look like parameters:

```
database_driver:   "%database_driver%"
database_host:     "%database_host%"
database_port:     "%database_port%"
database_name:     "%database_name%"
database_user:     "%database_user%"
database_password:  "%database_password%"
# You should uncomment this if you want use pdo_sqlite
# database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data.db3"

mailer_transport:  ~
mailer_host:       ~
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~

locale:            en

# A secret key that's used to generate certain security-related tokens
secret:            ~

#keys for GoodReads and Amazon API
goodreads_key:      ~
amazon_key:         ~
amazon_secret_key:  ~
amazon_tag:         ~
```

Comment: can you post the `parameters.yml.dist` files? PS: usually is better to make a special parameter for travis like parameters.ym.travis as described at [this](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2014/03/easy-travis-configuration-for-your-symfony2-tests-using-mysql-database/) useful link. Hope this help

Comment: Indeed, post your parameters file. It sounds like your parameters.yml is trying to read an environment variable of the same name.

Comment: parameters.yml.dist added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables, denoted by %%, are expected to be set as environment variables, which your travis build/user environment lacks.

Comment: You are right, changed them and everyting is working now